# System with exponential and log

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system in real numbers:
\begin{cases}
\log_2(x+y)+4=2^x+2^y \\
\frac{x+y}{4}+\frac{xy}{x+y}=1
\end{cases}

I used the fact that $\frac{xy}{x+y} \leq \frac{x+y}{4}$ in order to get $x+y \geq 2$, but I couldn't find even one solution afterwards.

Comment: you can solve the second equation for $y$ or $x$ and you can plug the in the first equation

Comment: i think a numerical method will help here